# How many adress bits will a memory of n bytes need?

Tags: byte, bit, memory-address

I'm having a hard time translating from one to the other. My problem probably is what a memory is and how it's defined and not the translation itself.

Say I have an adress with 1 bit. So it can be either 0 or 1, 2^1 possibilities. How much data can it hold?

In the case of a 16 bit address. There are 2^16 possibilities, which is 65536. And a 12 bit adress can hold 65536 **bytes** (64MB). Why is this? Shouldn't it hold 65536 **bits**?

By the same logic, 1 bit can hold 2 bytes. How can an adress that is either 0 or 1, hold 2 bytes of data?

EDIT: I had already searched for a while and some time after creating this post I came by a post explaining it. Basically 2^n are the number of possible addresses, and each address points to one byte. That's by the number of addresses = numbers of bytes

Answer (score 0):

I had already searched for a while and some time after creating this post I came by a post explaining it. Basically 2^n are the number of possible addresses, and each address points to one byte. That's by the number of addresses = numbers of bytes